Strange behaviour of GJK collision detection algorithm


In 1 image there is no collision, but in 2 there is
I have a bug with GJK algorithm. I am using glm library and I am facing a problem that when I increase the size of the model using matrix, GJK algorithm does not find collision(Some part of the object can be submerged in another object, but there is no collision)
Here is the code:
struct Vertex
{
    glm::vec3 pos;
    glm::vec3 color;
    glm::vec2 texCoord;
};

struct Mesh
{
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<uint32_t> indices;
    std::vector<glm::dvec3> hitBox;
    glm::dmat4 model;
    glm::dmat4 invModel;

    void setModel(const glm::dmat4 &model)
    {
        this->model = model;
        this->invModel = glm::inverse(model);
    }
};

enum class SimplexType 
{
    Zero,
    Point,
    Line,
    Triangle,
    Tetrahedron
};

struct Simplex
{
    std::list<glm::dvec3> points{};

    Simplex() = default;

    Simplex(std::initializer_list<glm::dvec3> list) 
    {
        for (const auto& v : list) 
        {
            points.push_back(v);
            if (points.size() > 4) 
            {
                points.pop_front();
            }
        }
    }

    void push_front(const glm::dvec3 &point) 
    {
        points.push_front(point);
        if (points.size() > 4) 
        {
            points.pop_back();
        }
    }

    glm::dvec3 operator[](size_t i) const 
    {
        auto it = points.begin();
        for (size_t k = 0; k < i; k++) 
        {
            ++it;
        }
        return *it;

    }

    [[nodiscard]] size_t size() const { return points.size(); }

    [[nodiscard]] auto begin() const { return points.begin(); }

    [[nodiscard]] auto end() const { return points.end(); }

    [[nodiscard]] SimplexType type() const { return static_cast<SimplexType>(points.size()); }
};

struct NextSimplex
{
    const Simplex newSimplex;
    const glm::dvec3 newDirection;
    const bool finishSearching;
};

class RigidBody
{
public:
    Mesh mesh;

    glm::dvec3 findFurthestPoint(const glm::dvec3 &direction)
    {
        glm::dvec3 maxPoint = glm::dvec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        double maxDistance = 0.0;

        glm::dvec3 transformedDirection = glm::normalize(this->mesh.invModel * glm::dvec4(direction, 0.0));

        for (auto &it : mesh.hitBox)
        {
            double distance = glm::dot(it, transformedDirection);

            if (distance > maxDistance)
            {
                maxDistance = distance;
                maxPoint = it;
            }
        }

        return mesh.model * glm::dvec4(maxPoint, 1.0);
    }

    glm::dvec3 support(RigidBody &obj, const glm::dvec3 &direction)
    {
        glm::dvec3 p1 = findFurthestPoint(direction);
        glm::dvec3 p2 = obj.findFurthestPoint(-direction);

        return p1 - p2;
    }

    NextSimplex lineCase(const Simplex &points)
    {
        Simplex newPoints(points);
        glm::dvec3 newDirection;

        glm::dvec3 a = points[0];
        glm::dvec3 b = points[1];

        glm::dvec3 ab = b - a;
        glm::dvec3 ao = -a;

        if (glm::dot(ab, ao) > 0)
        {
            newDirection = glm::cross(glm::cross(ab, ao), ab);
        }
        else
        {
            newPoints = Simplex{ a };
            newDirection = ao;
        }

        return NextSimplex{ newPoints, newDirection, false };
    }

    NextSimplex triangleCase(const Simplex &points)
    {
        Simplex newPoints(points);
        glm::dvec3 newDirection{};

        glm::dvec3 a = points[0];
        glm::dvec3 b = points[1];
        glm::dvec3 c = points[2];

        glm::dvec3 ab = b - a;
        glm::dvec3 ac = c - a;
        glm::dvec3 ao = -a;

        glm::dvec3 abc = glm::cross(ab, ac);

        if (glm::dot(glm::cross(abc, ac), ao) > 0)
        {
            if (glm::dot(ac, ao) > 0)
            {
                newPoints = Simplex{ a, c };
                newDirection = glm::cross(glm::cross(ac, ao), ac);
            }
            else
            {
                return lineCase(Simplex{ a, b });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (glm::dot(glm::cross(ab, abc), ao) > 0)
            {
                return lineCase(Simplex{ a, b });
            }
            else
            {
                if (glm::dot(abc, ao) > 0)
                {
                    newDirection = abc;
                }
                else
                {
                    newDirection = -abc;
                    newPoints = Simplex{ a, c, b };
                }
            }
        }

        return NextSimplex{ newPoints, newDirection, false };
    }

    NextSimplex tetrahedronCase(const Simplex &points)
    {
        glm::dvec3 a = points[0];
        glm::dvec3 b = points[1];
        glm::dvec3 c = points[2];
        glm::dvec3 d = points[3];

        glm::dvec3 ab = b - a;
        glm::dvec3 ac = c - a;
        glm::dvec3 ad = d - a;
        glm::dvec3 ao = -a;

        glm::dvec3 abc = glm::cross(ab, ac);
        glm::dvec3 acd = glm::cross(ac, ad);
        glm::dvec3 adb = glm::cross(ad, ab);

        if (glm::dot(abc, ao) > 0)
        {
            return triangleCase(Simplex{ a, b, c });
        }

        if (glm::dot(acd, ao) > 0)
        {
            return triangleCase(Simplex{ a, c, d });
        }

        if (glm::dot(adb, ao) > 0)
        {
            return triangleCase(Simplex{ a, d, b });
        }

        return NextSimplex(points, glm::dvec3(), true);
    }

    NextSimplex nextSimplex(const Simplex &points)
    {
        switch (points.type())
        {
        case SimplexType::Line:
            return lineCase(points);
        case SimplexType::Triangle:
            return triangleCase(points);
        case SimplexType::Tetrahedron:
            return tetrahedronCase(points);

        default:
            throw std::logic_error("Simplex is not line, triangle or tetrahedron");
        }
    }

    std::pair<bool, Simplex> checkGJKCollision(RigidBody &obj)
    {
        glm::dvec3 support = this->support(obj, glm::dvec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));

        Simplex points{};
        points.push_front(support);

        glm::dvec3 direction = -support;

        size_t iters = 0;
        while (++iters < mesh.vertices.size() + obj.mesh.vertices.size())
        {
            support = this->support(obj, direction);

            if (glm::dot(support, direction) <= 0)
                return std::make_pair(false, points);

            points.push_front(support);

            NextSimplex nextSimplex = this->nextSimplex(points);
            direction = nextSimplex.newDirection;
            points = nextSimplex.newSimplex;

            if (nextSimplex.finishSearching)
            {
                return std::make_pair(true, points);
            }
        }

        return std::make_pair(false, points);
    }
};

Code end
glm::dvec3 findFurthestPoint(const glm::dvec3 &direction)
{
    glm::dvec3 maxPoint = glm::dvec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    double maxDistance = 0.0;

    glm::dvec3 transformedDirection = glm::normalize(this->mesh.invModel * glm::dvec4(direction, 0.0));

    for (auto &it : mesh.hitBox)
    {
        double distance = glm::dot(it, transformedDirection);

        if (distance > maxDistance)
        {
            maxDistance = distance;
            maxPoint = it;
        }
    }

    return mesh.model * glm::dvec4(maxPoint, 1.0);
}

It should be noted that if you multiply "it" every iteration of the loop by the model matrix and replace glm::dot(..., transformedDirection) with glm::dot(..., direction), no errors occur. Perhaps the problem is with the invModel matrix, but I don't understand what the problem is. Where did I make the error?
Edited:
Code for creating model matrices(objAngleX, objAngleZ,  objX, objZ - have dynamical value):
auto modelMatrix = glm::translate(glm::dmat4(1.0), glm::dvec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
modelMatrix = glm::scale(modelMatrix, glm::dvec3(1.0, 1.5, 1.5));

box2.mesh.setModel(modelMatrix);
auto cameraPos = camera.position;
cameraPos.z -= 2.0;
modelMatrix = glm::translate(glm::dmat4(1.0), glm::dvec3(cameraPos));
modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, objAngleX, glm::dvec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, objAngleZ, glm::dvec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
modelMatrix = glm::scale(modelMatrix, glm::dvec3(0.3 + objX, 1.0, 0.3 + objZ));
box1.mesh.setModel(modelMatrix);

isCollision = box1.checkGJKCollision(box2).first; 


Without knowing the actual values where it is succeeding/failing, I can't guarantee that this is your problem, but I can guarantee that your code will fail as written in the following case anyways: When your two objects have support points that are collinear with the origin and initial search direction.
lineCase() will then be, for example (filling in the values)
    NextSimplex lineCase(const Simplex &points)
    {
        /* ASIDE: Just accept a Simplex by value instead of by reference 
           if you are just going to copy it as the first action. */
        Simplex newPoints(points);
        glm::dvec3 newDirection;

        glm::dvec3 a = points[0]; // {-2,0,0}
        glm::dvec3 b = points[1]; // {3,0,0}

        glm::dvec3 ab = b - a; // {5,0,0}
        glm::dvec3 ao = -a; // {2,0,0}

        if (glm::dot(ab, ao) > 0) // true
        {
            newDirection = glm::cross(glm::cross(ab, ao), ab); // {0,0,0} THE ISSUE!
        }
        else
        {
            newPoints = Simplex{ a };
            newDirection = ao;
        }

        /* You now have 0 as your search direction. You will probably get a 
           domain error in glm::normalize from this, when you should actually 
           return that you have a collision at this point (as you have concluded 
           the origin is actually inside your 1 simplex, and not just inside 
           it after projecting onto it). */
        return NextSimplex{ newPoints, newDirection, false };

        /* SECOND ASIDE: You don't actually need the normalize call in your 
           support function - you just need the index of the maximum dot product 
           with the direction, not the actual value of the projected length. A 
           uniform scale to the direction (all the dot products) will not change 
           the answer (unless you overflow/underflow, I suppose). */
    }

I think you also have the same issue with the triangleCase and a coplanar origin.
